# Cron expression to trigger on 25 of every month

Tags: java, spring, cron

How to write cron expression to trigger a function on 25th of every month at 9 A.M in the morning?

When I execute this code,

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class PayrollSchedulerImpl implements PayrollScheduler{

    @Scheduled(cron="0 9 25 1 * ?")
    public void calculateSalaryScheduled()
    {
        calculateSalary();
    }

    public void calculateSalary()
    {
        /* */
    }
}
```

I get the error,

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(Unknown Source)
    sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(Unknown Source)
    java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
    java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Calendar.complete(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Calendar.get(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.doNext(CronSequenceGenerator.java:130)
```

Comment: you can also validate the pattern like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112098/how-to-validate-cron-job-with-spring-boot/68218642#answer-68218642

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 9 25 1 * ?")
```

This is on January 1st only, and the time is invalid, you'll want this instead:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9 25 * ?")
```

**Reference:** [`CronSequenceGenerator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

Comment: I have Cron expression in my DB I'm fetching them.firstly how could I able to c check the Cron expression and then to trigger by Cron expression.

Comment: Or `@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9 25 1/1 ?")`

Answer (score 1):

Corn that will trigger every 25th of each month.

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 9 25 * ?")
```

use this link to validate the expression

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html