# How to validate cron job with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I want to have a cron job that executes every 00:10 am

according to online validators this is the correct expression "0 0/10 0/00 ? * * *"
but it has '?' and spring rejects this.

how can i validate my cron job properly ? my assumption is this should work  '0 0/10 0/00 * * *' but it doesnt, please can someone point me in the right direction ?  what am i doing wrong ? i will like to have a task 10 minutes after midnight

```
@Transactional
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 1/00 * * *")
    public void invalidateOutdatedPolicies() {
        InsurancePolicyStatus policyStatus =  
        System.out.println("Scheduled task done");
    }``
```

Comment: you can use www.cronmaker.com/ to generate your desire cron expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can validate pattern like this

```
public class ValidateCrontab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {week} {year (optional)}
        // Second time, day, month and week, these 6 items are mandatory.

        CronSequenceGenerator cron1 = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 05 10 23 * ?");
        
        CronSequenceGenerator cron2 = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 05 08 ? * MON-FRI");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 2); // add two days to current date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("current date " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) +"\n ----");

        System.out.println("Next cron trigger date cron1 " + cron1.next(cal.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Next cron trigger date cron2 " + cron2.next(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`CronSequenceGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)
has been deprecated since Spring 5.3, in favor of [`CronExpression`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html).

Here's an example.

```java
// validate if a cron expression is valid.

CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 0 4 L 11/3 SAT"); // output - true

// find next execution date for a cron.

final CronExpression expression = CronExpression.parse("0 0 4 L 11/3 SAT");
expression.next(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // output - 2024-11-30T04:00Z
```